# Display Vector elements in a reverse order

Tags: c++

I have two questions but they are interlinked.:

```
part:a->
```

I have been trying to display the elements of vector in reverse order. But nothing is working. I have used iterotar like;

```
for (it=vec.end(); it!=vec.begin(); --it){ 
// it is iterator not reverse_iterator.
// do work
}
```

P.S I am not much familiar with iterators. I have used them for the first time today to 
display elem in reverse order.

also tried;

```
for (int i=vec.size(); i!=0; i--){
//display
}
```

No matter what I do it always display the elem in same order as they are present i.e not in the reverse order.

```
part_b->
```

Is there any way that I can store the output of a recursive function direct into a vector. like the code is: 
I know this does not work. I have tried but just giving you an idea 
what I am upto.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "vector"

int func(int num);
vector <int> vec;

int main() {
    int num=34;
    // I know this would not work. But is there any possibilitiy that
    // I can store the output in a vector.
    vec = binary(num);                          

    // trying to display the vector.        
    for (int i=vec.size();i!=0;i--) {
        cout<<vec[i]<<" ";
    } // not working for reverse display.
} //main.

int func(int num) {
    if (num==1) {
        //vec.push_back(1);
        return 1;
    }
    else if(num==0) {
        //vec.push_back(0);
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        //vec.push_back(input%2);
        return binary(input/2);
    }
} //func.
```

I hope you do unnderstand the question. if I am able to do the part b the  there is no need to reverse the elem of the vector.

Comment: for (int i= (V.size() - 1) ;i!=0;i--) {cout<<vec[i]<<" ";}

Comment: It is not displaying the last elem.

Comment: I mean first one.i.e Last one in reversed order.

Comment: @sgar91 No. Get in the habit of using iterators everywhere. Don’t use index variables – they’re error-prone (fencepost errors etc.) and completely useless most of the time. Using iterators also means that you can effortlessly transition to algorithms instead of loops (which is *always* better) or range-based `for` in C++11.

Comment: sorry. my mistake. for (int i= (V.size() - 1) ;i>=0;i--)

Comment: @KonradRudolph.. thankyou for your advice. I'll keep that in mind. Actually i'm used to index based array iteration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard solution uses reverse iterators:

```
for (auto it = v.rbegin(); it != v.rend(); ++it)
{
    if (it != v.rbegin()) { std::cout << ' '; }
    std::cout << *it;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use indices, but keep the "reversal" idiom and *increment* the index:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i != v.size(); ++i)
{
    if (i != 0) { std::cout << ' '; }
    std::cout << v[v.size() - i - 1];
}
```

Note that reverse iterators are literally just doing something very similar to the explicit loop under the hood. In particular, the `base()` member function of a reverse iterator gives you the corresponding ordinary iterator offset by one, just as we have a `- 1` in the index computation. (E.g. `rbegin()` is just `end()` under the hood, but decrements by one upon dereferencing.)

Comment: "it" is reverse_iterator or just iterator;
How would I define it like 
vector <int>::iterator it;
If yes, I am having following error

Comment: @HardCode you should compile with `C++11` or `C++0x` enabled

Comment: I am using GNU as a compiler

Comment: gcc supports c++11, you only have to give the right parameters

Comment: @HardCode: just pass the flag -std=c++0x (up until gcc4.6) or -std=c++11 (gcc4.7+). But really, you can find this with a 5s search.

Answer (score 2):

Use reverse iterators:

```
for (auto it = vec.crend(); it != vec.crbegin(); ++it) {
    std::cout << *it << ' ';
}
std::cout << '\n';
```

Comment: If your compiler doesn't support this use of `auto` (i.e. doesn't do C++11), use `std::vector<int>::const_reverse_iterator` for the type.

Comment: @Pete If the compiler doesn’t support `auto` it most probably also doesn’t support `crend` and `crbegin`. ;-)

Comment: @KonradRudolph - `crbegin` and `crend` are simple library additions that have no effects on anything else. They've been available in some implementations for several years. Adding `auto` is much more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

**Part A**

Assuming you haven't got access to C++11:

```
vector<int>::const_reverse_iterator it;
for (it=vec.rbegin(); it!=vec.rend(); ++it)
{ 
    // do work
}
```

**Part B**

It looks very much like you're trying to display a number in binary. Unfortunately the standard flags on ostream only allow hex, decimal or octal as far as I'm aware, but can I suggest a simpler way of doing this?

```
#include <bitset>

bitset< sizeof(int) << 3 > b(34);
cout << b << endl;
```

Which gives:

```
00000000000000000000000000100010
```

The rather ugly looking `sizeof(int) << 3` is just a way of getting the size of an `int` in  bits to avoid truncation.

Comment: Doesn’t compile – you cannot modify a `const` iterator.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Indeed - meant `const_reverse_iterator`. Change that now.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote little program which may help. Maybe your vector is empty?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    vector<int> vec;
    vec.insert(vec.begin(), 1, 1);
    vec.insert(vec.begin(), 1, 2);
    vec.insert(vec.begin(), 1, 3);
    vector<int>::iterator i;
    for (i = vec.end(); i != vec.begin(); --i)
    {
        cout << *i;
    }
    cout << *i;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is still wrong, you dereference `end()`, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: Maybe this behaviour is undefined in standard, however it is defined in stl.

Comment: no it isn't, the standard defines `std::vector` and as far as I know dereferencing `end()` is undefined behavior. Btw: STL is an ancient thing from the eighties, it is still commonly used to refer to the containers part of the c++ standard library, but it is not at all a modern standard.

Comment: @Linkas No it isn’t. What do you expect the result of dereferencing `end()` to be, anyway? It doesn’t reference any useful value. Your code simply won’t work. It will either crash or output garbage.